# AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

for python3 user, the tutorial suggest to run:

```
$ catkin_make -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3
```

to build the workspace.

however, following error may come:

```
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
```

https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/1582

found one answer from github, it says this error is caused by `enum34`, which is not support in newer version python3. if you uninstall this module, the error will be solved. but to uninstall enum34, you need to uninstall the melodic ROS also.

can anyone contact the maintainer to help to solve this weird issue???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347177/attributeerror:-module-%27enum%27-has-no-attribute-%27intflag%27/) by [Mr.Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/52721/mr.gao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2020-03-20

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my case (inside a 20.04 docker with noetic) enum34 was installed via pip, and no other packages were depending on it, so this worked:

```
pip3 uninstall -y enum34
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2020-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1